# Most efficient way to trigger hover state for mulitple nth-child items in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-selectors

I have table where the top border of the first, second and third td in the first tr need to change color when hovering the corresponding td.

My constraint is that I cannot use anymore classes or ID's because these table styles are going to be used by people that have little to no experience in wirting code they just select a table in our cms and add one class and id to it.

I have the code working (see bottom snippet) but I want to code it as efficient as possible for the following child object.

I could do this:

```js
$("#table1 td:nth-child(1)").hover(function() {
  $("#table1.table-equal-compare-3 tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(1)").addClass("table-compare-border-hover");
}, function() {
  $("#table1.table-equal-compare-3 tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(1)").removeClass("table-compare-border-hover");
});

$("#table1 td:nth-child(2)").hover(function() {
  $("#table1.table-equal-compare-3 tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(2)").addClass("table-compare-border-hover");
}, function() {
  $("#table1.table-equal-compare-3 tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(2)").removeClass("table-compare-border-hover");
});

$("#table1 td:nth-child(3)").hover(function() {
  $("#table1.table-equal-compare-3 tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(3)").addClass("table-compare-border-hover");
}, function() {
  $("#table1.table-equal-compare-3 tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(3)").removeClass("table-compare-border-hover");
});
```

But that seems horribly inefficient especially since the page can have up to 4 tables, then i would need to repeat above code for #table1, #table2, #table3 and #table4

Below is my full code

```js
$("#table1 td:nth-child(1)").hover(function() {
  $("#table1.table-equal-compare-3 tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(1)").addClass("table-compare-border-hover");
}, function() {
  $("#table1.table-equal-compare-3 tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(1)").removeClass("table-compare-border-hover");
});
```

```css
.table-equal-compare-3 tr:nth-child(1) {
  border-top: solid 2px #e6e6e6;
}

table.table-equal-compare-3 td {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.table-compare-border-hover {
  border-top: solid 2px #000;
  -webkit-transition: border-top-color 500ms linear;
  -ms-transition: border-top-color 500ms linear;
  transition: border-top-color 500ms linear;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="0" class="table-equal-compare-3" id="table1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="text-align: center;"><strong>Axitour AXIWI REF-001</strong></td>
      <td style="text-align: center;"><strong>Axitour AXIWI REF-002</strong></td>
      <td style="text-align: center;"><strong>Axitour AXIWI REF-004</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="240">
        <div>2 Zenders&nbsp;(AXIWI AT-320 LD)</div>
        <div>2 Sportheadsets</div>
        <div>Transportkoffer</div>
      </td>
      <td width="240">
        <div>3&nbsp;Zenders&nbsp;(AXIWI AT-320 LD)</div>
        <div>3&nbsp;Sportheadsets</div>
        <div>• Transportkoffer</div>
      </td>
      <td width="240">
        <div>5 Zenders (AXIWI AT-320 LD)</div>
        <div>5 Sportheadsets</div>
        <div>Transportkoffer</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're using a `table` for this? It seems like the problem could be solved much more simply by using `div` elements properly along with CSS `:hover` selectors. Your hard-coded `•` characters are also very odd. Use a `<ul>` and `<li>` elements

Comment: That would be a easy solution, the problem is that all of our existing pages use tables and they can be auto generated by our cms (wysiwyg). Using divs would mean the people that are going to make these pages (copywriters) need to edit the source code which they cannot and are not payed for.

Comment: Not all tds, only the first three td's in the frist tr.

Comment: you only have three tds

Comment: My bad, code is not complete there are going to be more td's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a more appropriate CSS selector instead. The following is a pure CSS3 selector:

```
td:nth-child(-n + 3)
```

... that matches all `td` elements that are 1st, 2nd and 3rd child of their parent. Your code could be simplified as follows:

```js
$("#table1 td:nth-child(-n + 3)").hover(function() {
  var n = $(this).index() + 1;
  $("#table1 tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(" + n + ")").addClass("table-compare-border-hover");
}, function() {
  var n = $(this).index() + 1;
  $("#table1 tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(" + n + ")").removeClass("table-compare-border-hover");
});
```

```css
.table-equal-compare-3 td {
  border-top: solid 2px transparent;
  transition: border-top-color 500ms linear;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

td.table-compare-border-hover {
  border-top-color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="0" class="table-equal-compare-3" id="table1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Label 1</td>
      <td>Label 2</td>
      <td>Label 3</td>
      <td>Label 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Value 1</td>
      <td>Value 2</td>
      <td>Value 3</td>
      <td>Value 4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to use Javascript. Simple CSS will do this for you.

```css
table tr:first-child > td:hover {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<table border="0" class="table-equal-compare-3" id="table1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="text-align: center;"><strong>Axitour AXIWI REF-001</strong></td>
      <td style="text-align: center;"><strong>Axitour AXIWI REF-002</strong></td>
      <td style="text-align: center;"><strong>Axitour AXIWI REF-004</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="240">
        <div>2 Zenders&nbsp;(AXIWI AT-320 LD)</div>
        <div>2 Sportheadsets</div>
        <div>Transportkoffer<br> &nbsp;
        </div>
      </td>
      <td width="240">
        <div>3&nbsp;Zenders&nbsp;(AXIWI AT-320 LD)</div>
        <div>3&nbsp;Sportheadsets</div>
        <div>• Transportkoffer<br> &nbsp;
        </div>
      </td>
      <td width="240">
        <div>5 Zenders (AXIWI AT-320 LD)</div>
        <div>5 Sportheadsets</div>
        <div>Transportkoffer<br> &nbsp;
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Yes, but only when hovering the td itself, the hover needs to trigger on the whole column. Didn't mention this correctly

Answer (score 1):

I would use `index()` to get the index of the current cell in the row and then use that to add and remove a class on the first row:

```js
var table = $('.table-equal-compare-3'),
    firstRowTDs = table.find('tr').eq(0).children();  // cache the first row tds for better performance
    
table.find('td').hover(function() {
  var index = $(this).index();
  
  if (index < 3) {  // only do this to first three columns
    firstRowTDs
      .removeClass('hovered') // remove all classes
      .eq(index)    // get the item that matches the index of the hovered element
      .addClass('hovered');   // add top border
  }
}, 
function () {
  firstRowTDs.removeClass('hovered');  // remove top border
});
```

```css
.table-equal-compare-3 tr:nth-child(1) {
  border-top: solid 2px #e6e6e6;
}

table.table-equal-compare-3 td {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

table.table-equal-compare-3 tr:first-child td {
  border-top: solid 2px transparent;
  -webkit-transition: border-top-color 500ms linear;
  -ms-transition: border-top-color 500ms linear;
  transition: border-top-color 500ms linear;
}

table.table-equal-compare-3 tr:first-child td.hovered {
  border-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="0" class="table-equal-compare-3" id="table1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="text-align: center;"><strong>Axitour AXIWI REF-001</strong></td>
      <td style="text-align: center;"><strong>Axitour AXIWI REF-002</strong></td>
      <td style="text-align: center;"><strong>Axitour AXIWI REF-003</strong></td>
      <td style="text-align: center;"><strong>Axitour AXIWI REF-004</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="240">
        <div>2 Zenders&nbsp;(AXIWI AT-320 LD)</div>

        <div>2 Sportheadsets</div>

        <div>Transportkoffer<br> &nbsp;
        </div>
      </td>
      <td width="240">
        <div>3&nbsp;Zenders&nbsp;(AXIWI AT-320 LD)</div>

        <div>3&nbsp;Sportheadsets</div>

        <div>• Transportkoffer<br> &nbsp;
        </div>
      </td>
      <td width="240">
        <div>5 Zenders (AXIWI AT-320 LD)</div>

        <div>5 Sportheadsets</div>

        <div>Transportkoffer<br> &nbsp;
        </div>
      </td>
      <td width="240">
        <div>extra column that doesn't have hover on top</div>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```